# How do I say that I will do something after everything else?

Tags: phrase-usage

Is the expression "I will do it at the end" appropriate for saying that I will do something after everything else?

I'm not sure if it sounds natural and suspect it might have a different meaning -- I will do it eventually.

Comment: I have edited your question for grammar, but I don't understand your second paragraph. Does it refer to your first example or the second example?

Comment: it refers to the first example.
I had a suspicion that "I will do it at the end" sounds like "I will do it eventually/ultimately"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fine. There are alternatives:

> - I will do it last.
> - It will be the last thing I do.
> - Finally, I will do it.
> - I will do it ultimately.

where, in the final case, ultimately is being used as an adverb, meaning *finally; in the end (Google)*.

Comment: I like _finally_ best.

Comment: "it will be the last thing I do" could suggest you'll never get around to it.  If you're planning on doing it, it would be better to add something positive--"it will be the last thing I do before I leave tonight", e.g.

Comment: “finally, I will do it” sounds like you’ve been wanting to do it for a long time and now you finally have the chance.  “I will do it ultimately.” sounds like you will get around to it at some point but not anytime soon. “I will do it last” is the only reasonable option here to indicate the order in which you will do a list of things.